org-ref seems to not find references in the bibtex.bib file
I have a large bibliography library.bib file and I was trying to insert some older references into an org file. My file is about 9mb right now. For some reason, org-ref or helm-bibtex cannot find the reference in the bib file, even though I used the KBibtex software to look at the bibtex file and ensure that the reference is there.
So I have 100% confidence that the reference entry is in the bib file, but org-ref or helm-bibtex is not finding it.
Is there a way to force org-ref or helm-bibtex to look through the entire file? I can provide a copy of the bibtex entry if that helps. But the entry seems to be correctly formatted, so no issues there.
It just seems like newer entries are easily detected by older entries in the file are somehow not found?
